# Pulling paragraphs from outlook emails and importing them into .txt or .doc

Tags: python, filter, outlook, compilation, office-automation

so the script I'm trying to write in Python would search for certain subjects such as "City status update" and "City issues" in my inbox and search for variables such as the city names. if the city names are in the email then it would pull that whole line of text to the period (.) and load it into a .txt file. Such as "Detroit: Cakes 15, Pies 12, Drinks 19." and not pull anything else. Below are two examples of the format for the emails along with what I have so far.

Subject: City status update

Detroit: Cakes 15, Pies 12, Drinks 19.
New York: Cakes 9, Pies 14, Drinks 2.

Subject: City issues

Detroit: 2 lost items, 2 unclaimed, 6 delivered.
Chicago: 5 lost items, 1 unclaimed, 9 delivered.
New York: 7 lost items, 3 unclaimed, 16 delivered.

```
import win32com.client
import os, re, html

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("OutlookApplication").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
messages = inbox.items
message = messages.GetFirst()

subject = message.Subject

city = input("What city/cities are you looking for?")

for message in messages:
  if message.Subject ["City status update, City issues"]
    name =str(message.subject)
    regex = re.search(r"city", msg.HTMLbody)
    body = regex.group()

OlSaveAsType = {
  "olTXT": 0,
  "olRTF": 1,
  "olTemplate": 2,
  "olMSG": 3,
  "olDoc": 4,
  "olHTML": 5,
  "olVCard": 6,
  "olVCal": 7,
  "olICal": 8
}

    message.SaveAs(os.getcwd()+'//'+name, OlSaveAsType(['olTXT])

    results = body

r = re.compile('.*/.*/.*:.*')
 if results, True
    print(results - ["."])

 else()
```

This is what I have so far and a bunch of errors.

Comment: There seems to be an indentation error in your code (see the `message.SaveAs` line ). Also, can you include information about the errors that you're getting? Please include the traceback

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to iterate over all items in a folder.

```
for message in messages:
  if message.Subject ["City status update, City issues"]
    name =str(message.subject)
    regex = re.search(r"city", msg.HTMLbody)
    body = regex.group()
```

Instead, the Outlook object model provides the `Find`/`FindNext` or Restrict methods of the `Items` class. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

To deal with a message body I'd suggest using the Word object model. The `WordEditor` property of the `Inspector` class returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed.

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the MailItem class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the Body property immediately.
3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.